# Why does Dart have compile time constants?

Tags: dart

Dart has the concept of compile-time constants. A compile-time constant is parsed and created at compile time, and canonicalized.

For example, here is a `const` constructor for Point:

```
class Point {
  final num x, y;
  const Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
main() {
  var p1 = const Point(0, 0);
  var p2 = const Point(0, 0);
  print(p1 == p2); // true
  print(p1 === p2); // true
}
```

This is a non-obvious feature, with seemingly no parallels to features in other dynamic languages. There are restrictions on `const` objects, like all fields must be final and it must have a const constructor.

Why does Dart have compile-time constants?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/pR2ClUIB_Aw), Florian Loitsch writes:

> The canonicalization property of compile-time constants is nice, but
>   not the main-reason to have them. The real benefit of compile-time
>   constants is, that they don't allow arbitrary execution at
>   construction and can therefore be used at places where we don't want
>   code to executed. Static variables initializers, for example, were
>   initially restricted to compile-time constants to avoid execution at
>   the top-level. In short, they make sure that a program starts with
>   'main' and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Lasse's answer [here](https://japhr.blogspot.com/2012/12/dart-constant-constructors.html?showComment=1356818172588#c8522270242427745784) helped me a lot

> So, what are compile-time constants good for anyway?
>
> - They are useful for enums.
> - You can use compile-time constant values in switch cases.
> - They are used as annotations.
>
> **Compile-time constants used to be more important before Dart switched
>   to lazily initializing variables**. Before that, you could only declare
>   an initialized global variable like "var x = foo;" if "foo" was a
>   compile-time constant. Without that requrirement, most programs can be
>   written without using any const objects