# Is Const for creating Singleton Objects?

Tags: dart

From [Why does Dart have compile time constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12418819/6045800):

> Dart has the concept of compile-time constants. A compile-time
> constant is parsed and created at compile time, and canonicalized.
>
> For example, here is a `const` constructor for Point:
>
> ```
> class Point {
>   final num x, y;
>   const Point(this.x, this.y);
> }
> ```
>
> And here's how you use it:
>
> ```
> main() {
>   var p1 = const Point(0, 0);
>   var p2 = const Point(0, 0);
>   print(p1 == p2); // true
>   print(p1 === p2); // true
> }
> ```

This code snippet was from Stack Overflow I am reusing this good example, thanks again.
Const I have noticed is used alot in flutter widgets.

Does that mean that we can use `const` to create Singleton Objects?

Answer (score 0):

To create a singleton, check out the following answer: [How do you build a Singleton in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart)

There is a difference between `const` and `final`, which can be found here: [What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)

But in short, you can't use `const` for singleton objects, as the object is not a compile time constant. You'll need to use `final`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the  useful reply, appreciate it.
I did not know this especially
When you declare  a list as final and you can still append values to it however when its marked const you can not even add new values:
Almost like final is like the const in javascript and the const is the real const thats missin gin javascript

Answer (score 0):

No. `const` constructors have a very different purpose from the singleton pattern.

A `singleton` aims to ensure that **only one instance** of the class exists in the program. For example, you have an `Area` class in your program. You want only one `area` object instance to exist so you implement it as a `singleton` (Look link in another answer).

Then, every time you call `Area()` it returns the same instance:

```
Area().setPoint(const Point(1, 2));
Area().setPoint(const Point(11, 12));
Area().setPoint(const Point(21, 22));
```

Now, the purpose of `const` is to improve performance. Flutter will not rebuild the widget if it is defined as `const`. But you can create as many different instances of `Point` as you wish.